# Apache userdir with custom url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-userdir

[mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.htm) seems to be able customize where the home folders are, but is there a way to make those available under a custom URL?

I want to provide users with a url like the following:
`http://example.com/arbitrarystring/[user]`

Comment: I suspect you need to look at `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @Zoredache I was hoping to avoid it, but I will if there's no other choice. Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: any particular reason to why you would rather avoid `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Since `mod_rewrite` is such a complex module, I assume (perhaps mistakenly) that it'll be so much easier to come up with an insecure configuration. Also, I imagine there's some performance hit, though that's not particularly relevant in my usecase. `mod_userdir` just seems tailor-made for this purpose, and I keep wondering why it's still there (in apache) if `mod_rewrite` is capable of emulating it (which I know it does). I'll readily accept a mod_rewrite answer here, if there's really no other choice

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely doable. I did just that and recorded the efforts [here](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/15832.html). This is a solution that does use mod-rewrite, but not deep wizardry. The problem we had was that when we were implementing user_dirs, The Powers That Be thought using a shift key to get at a directory was too much work and wanted a tilde-free version. That's a one character version of what you're doing.

The meat is in the `RewriteRule` statements.

```
RewriteRule  ^/somestring/([a-z0-9]+)         /~$1    [R]
```

The problem here is that `/~username` will still work. You can possibly get around that by using an internal proxy-redirect to another hidden domain name.

```
RewriteRule ^/somestring/(a-z0-9]+)        http://othervhost.example.com/~$1      [PT]
```

Comment: Since no one came up with an answer using just `mod_userdir`, and your solution is well documented, I'm awarding you the bounty. Thanks for sharing!